# GHC warning for irrefutable pattern in let binding

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a chess program in Haskell, and while testing at runtime, I encountered an `Irrefutable pattern failed...` error.

I have the following datatypes:

```
data Color = ...
data Piece = ...
data CPiece = CP Color Piece | Null
```

And the problem occurs at:

```
let startPiece = getPiece board start in
  let CP startColor _ = startPiece in
```

`getPiece` returns `CPiece`, and I know I didn't account for the `Null` constructor and should use a `case getPiece board start of ...` statement instead.

However, why isn't GHC producing any warning? I have turned on `-Wall` and `-Wincomplete-uni-patterns`, and I'm using GHC 8.0.2 on Debian.

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem.  If I turn your code fragments into a compilable example, then compiling with GHC 8.0.2 and `-Wincomplete-uni-patterns` generates a non-exhaustive pattern match warning, as expected.  Can you provide a *complete* compilable example that fails to generate the warning?

Comment: [Here](https://repl.it/repls/WateryShamelessCottonmouth) is a minimal example which shows that GHC does indeed issue the appropriate warning. However, `-Wall` is not enough here - the user guide explicitly lists `-Wincomplete-uni-patterns` as one of the warnings *not* enabled by `-Wall` ([ref](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html)).

Comment: I realised that it's because `ghc` wasn't even compiling: the source file had already been compiled previously and remained unchanged. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake; `ghc` runs in [make mode](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using.html#make-mode) by default, and while trying the different switches, I had run:

```
$ ghc -Wall file.hs
$ ghc -Wall -Wincomplete-uni-patterns file.hs
```

consecutively. The second invocation of `ghc` would not compile `file.hs` because it had already been compiled and unmodified since the first invocation.

Running

```
$ touch file.hs
$ ghc -Wall -Wincomplete-uni-patterns file.hs
```

to update the timestamp of the source file followed by compilation produces the `Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive` warning as I had wanted.

Comment: You can also pass the `-fforce-recomp` to GHC to make it recompile everything.